# How do I use custom preload in gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have these 2 structs

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name      string
  CompanyID int
  Company   Company
}

type Company struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
  Adress string
}
```

I want to get users and preload their companies but I don't want to get the Adress field I tried the custom preload like bellow and I tested it in postman . the query returned all the fields but for adress I get an empty string , the reason why this is happening is that when storing the result in the user struct golang automatically initialize all the fields and the field adress get returned with its initial value which is an empty sting

```
var user []User
     db.Table("users").Preload("Company",func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Select("ID" ,"Name")
    }).Find(&user)
```

what should I do to only have the name and id but not the adress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server exports the result as json you could add the json tag omitempty as such:

```
type Company struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Adress string `json:"omitempty"`
}
```

That way the address field will not be included if it is an empty string.